Are there any graphics adapters that work not on a bus slot, but on USB-C?

I have a Ryzen 7 7840 in a case 6" wide. The processor is asskick, but my only graphics is the puny on-die AMD graphics that won't run Second Life.
Does anybody make a USB-4 external graphics adaptor?

That's usually just called "eGPU", or external GPU. In most cases that's an enclosure for a normal graphics card which includes its own power supply and is connected through USB / Thunderbolt. Is that what you want? They tend to be very expensive though.

@towe Ohh my god! I almost didn't ask because I thought I was a stupid question! I'm going to look them up right now. I hope they have these adaptors for Nvidia. The EGA wonder was the last decent ATI card. === Is that what you want?  === I want world peace and someone I can trust, but since both are equally probable, that'll certainly do.  === They tend to be very expensive though. === Doesn't matter. I do all the ordering for this place and I live on this. Got a 5.2 GHz Ryzen with the new partitionable bus.

OK, it turns out they're even cheap if you buy them without the case! I wish I knew about these five years ago. I just ordered this and a 40 Gb cable. You ought to get a commission. THANX!

Fair warning, the one you linked uses Oculink with an included M.2 adapter. Your mini PC probably has an M.2 slot, but then you would need to put a hole in the case. The ones that run on USB4 require more processing and so are a bit more expensive, but also more portable and don't require you to mod the case. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CNXNGYF9

@Alphy13 uh-oh. Why would I have to put a hole in the case? The M.2 drive is already inside the case, and the PCIe bus extension works over USB.

The Oculink cable needs to plug into the M.2 adapter. It's not the same cable as USB-C and Thunderbolt3/4.

The Oculink thing will work if you leave the case off, but USB4 is easier and will let you move it to another computer if you wanted to.

@Alphy13 so what case has to be off? There's one cable between this bus extender and the PC, namely USB4. So what case do I have to go through? The case on the PC? What do I have to access in there? My M.2 drive? What does that have to do with anything? I knew this was too good to be true.

You'd need a way to get the Oculink cable out of the PCs case. The one you posted wouldn't use the USB 4 connection at all, but rather go like:
m.2 PCIe connector -> Oculink adapter board -> Oculink cable -> eGPU board
The one @Alphy13 posted is USB 4 -> USB-C cable -> eGPU board
It's different technology: That Oculink setup is basically just a thin PCIe extender cable.
